# Pagination of firebase realtime database does not work

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have read a lot of questions and answers, but none of them work for me.

This is JSON data in database:

```json
{
  "album": {
    "-NXo7t91rX0sbxc79yqy": {
      "items": [
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=4903898745667584",
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=5787447254319104",
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=1750740448051200"
      ]
    },
    "-NXoGPcxv6ez7CGRquXQ": {
      "items": [
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=6883601295605760",
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=5700479268945920",
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=3218840712380416"
      ]
    },
    "-NXoGdD24Lj6m9-LVpGS": {
      "items": [
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=2990041273991168",
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=5678303266471936",
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=3669263225192448"
      ]
    },
    "-NXoGdo6jOPI3uBvp2F9": {
      "items": [
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=3386698780114944",
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=840735259623424",
        "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=4960055438868480"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The API controller tries to implement the pagination.

```
router.get('/album/list', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query)
  let { limit = 2, lastKey = null } = req.query as unknown as { limit: number, lastKey: string, };
  const ref = admin.database().ref('album').orderByKey()
  console.log('limit: ', limit)
  if (lastKey) {
    ref.limitToFirst(Number(limit) + 1).startAt(lastKey)
  } else {
    ref.limitToFirst(Number(limit));
  }

  ref.once('value', (data) => {
    data.forEach((snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot.val(), snapshot.key)
      lastKey = snapshot.key;
    })
    res.status(200).json({ code: 0, message: null, result: { lastKey, albums: data.val() } })
  }, err => {
    console.error(err)
    res.status(500).json({ code: 1, message: 'Get data error' });
  })
})
```

I expect the `result` should have two items for the first page, but the it always returns all items. The response body:

```json
{
  "code": 0,
  "message": null,
  "result": {
    "lastKey": "-NXoGdo6jOPI3uBvp2F9",
    "albums": {
      "-NXo7t91rX0sbxc79yqy": {
        "items": [
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=4903898745667584",
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=5787447254319104",
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=1750740448051200"
        ]
      },
      "-NXoGPcxv6ez7CGRquXQ": {
        "items": [
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=6883601295605760",
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=5700479268945920",
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=3218840712380416"
        ]
      },
      "-NXoGdD24Lj6m9-LVpGS": {
        "items": [
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=2990041273991168",
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=5678303266471936",
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=3669263225192448"
        ]
      },
      "-NXoGdo6jOPI3uBvp2F9": {
        "items": [
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=3386698780114944",
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=840735259623424",
          "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/city?lock=4960055438868480"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

package version: `"firebase-admin": "^11.9.0"`